# AVAnimator crashing with 'movieFilePath is nil'

Tags: ios7

I've added the AVAnimator library to an existing project (ARC enabled) in order to add video with transparency to my iOS app and I am having trouble getting the animations to play or the app to even run. This exception keeps getting thrown:

> *** Assertion failure in +[AVFileUtil getResourcePath:], /Classes/AVAnimator/AVFileUtil.m:35
>   2014-02-20 11:12:49.091 [3977:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'movieFilePath is nil'

The video.7z is included in the project, but I am apparently missing something.

Here is my viewController code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
[super viewDidLoad];

animationView = [AVAnimatorView aVAnimatorViewWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,600,768)];
media = [AVAnimatorMedia aVAnimatorMedia];
NSString* movieResourceFilename = @"globe02.mvid";
AV7zAppResourceLoader *resLoader = [AV7zAppResourceLoader aV7zAppResourceLoader];
resLoader.archiveFilename = @"globe02.7z";
resLoader.movieFilename = movieResourceFilename;
resLoader.outPath = [AVFileUtil getTmpDirPath:movieResourceFilename];
media.resourceLoader = resLoader;
AVMvidFrameDecoder *frameDecoder = [AVMvidFrameDecoder aVMvidFrameDecoder];
media.frameDecoder = frameDecoder;
//media.animatorFrameDuration = AVAnimator30FPS;      
[media prepareToAnimate];

[self.view addSubview:animationView];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(animatorDoneNotification:)
                                             name:AVAnimatorDoneNotification
                                           object:media];}

- (void)animatorDoneNotification:(NSNotification*)notification {
NSLog( @"animatorDoneNotification" );
[animationView attachMedia:media];
[media startAnimator];}
```

Anyone with a clue as to what I am missing here?

Comment: The most likely case is that you forgot to add the "globe02.7z" archive to the project of the file name is spelled incorrectly. It is also possible that something is wrong with the data, but the nil basically just means it does not exist or could not be loaded. You will need to recheck the basics and compare that to a known working example (just use one of the examples on my webpage).

Comment: I had done just that. I attempted to load one of the example files from the StreetfighterII project. Same problem. I think I will put this on the back burner and comeback to it when I have some more time to play with it. As for my current project, I'll just use a video with a pre-rendered background so I won't have to mess with alpha channel.

Answer (score 0):

The code that generates that assert is:

```
NSString* movieFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:resFilename ofType:nil];
NSAssert(movieFilePath, @"movieFilePath is nil");
```

So, the problem was that iOS could not load @"globe02.7z" from the app resources, likely because you did not include that file in the build settings. It is a very minor configuration error in your project file.